# rsync rules file causing files not copied

Tags: rsync

I have two shell scripts for synchronising data with the remore, one called `out.sh` which is supposed to sync local data to the remote and the other called `in.sh` which is supposed to sync the local data from the remote.

`out.sh` reads the command

```
rsync -azEX \
      --itemize-changes \
      --info=BACKUP1,DEL1,NAME1,REMOVE1 \
      --delete \
      --exclude-from=$EXCLUDE_FILE \
      $BCK_SRC $SSH_BCK_DST
```

`in.sh` reads the command

```
rsync -azEX \
      --itemize-changes \
      --info=BACKUP1,DEL1,NAME1,REMOVE1 \
      --delete \
      --exclude-from=$EXCLUDE_FILE \
      $SSH_BCK_SRC $BCK_DST
```

The exclude file is:

```
+ /dir1/***
+ /dir2/***
+ /dir3/***
- /***
```

When I make changes on the local in some file in `dir1`, and then run `out.sh`, nothing is copied over, however, `in.sh` copies over the old file from the remote. It should not I think. But more important is that `out.sh` does nothing. When I delete the last line in the exclude file, then `out.sh` copies over the files as expected.

Question 1: How to make the exclude file correctly, so that it only syncs the contents of the directories after the + sign and nothing else.

Question 2: Is the behaviour that `in.sh` copies older files over the newer files correct?

Comment: What version of `rsync` is installed on each of the computers (`/***` was added in v2.6.7)? As for keeping newer files, I think you want to add `--update`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Both are running `rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31` both are basically the same machines (Debian stable) when it comes to SW.